# Urban Fantasy Female Protagonist Sent to Alternative Dimension

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

Looking for a book in which a policewoman of some variety is pulled/sent into an alternative dimension in order to solve a crime that they do not have the expertise to solve.  She is not best pleased and almost kills the vampire official who has broght her over, apparently with the blessing of her usual bosses.

She is told that she can go back when the crime is solved, but it becomes apparent they have no intention of returning her anytime soon.

Comment: That actually sounds a bit like one of the Sookie Stackhouse stories, but those are all set in one universe.

Answer (score 8):

I've never read the book, but it sounds a lot like [Dying Bites](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312942583) (Book 1 in Bloodhound Files series) by D D Barant.

> Her job description is the “tracking and apprehension of mentally-fractured killers.” What this really means in FBI profiler Jace Valchek’s brave new world—one in which only one percent of the population is human—is that a woman’s work is never done. And real is getting stranger every day…
>
>   Jace has been ripped from her reality by David Cassius, the vampire head of the NSA. He knows that she’s the best there in the business, and David needs her help in solving a series of gruesome murders of vampires and werewolves. David’s world—one that also includes lycanthropes and golems—is one with little knowledge of mental illness. An insane serial killer is a threat the NSA has no experience with. But Jace does. Stranded in a reality where Bela Lugosi is a bigger box office draw than Bruce Willis and every full moon is Mardi Gras, Jace must now hunt down a fellow human before he brings the entire planet to the brink of madness. Or she may never see her own world again…